# Why Downloading play-service-base-16.0.0.pom Everytime I run project in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I am using Android Studio now, and every time I want to run my project, it will download 'play-service-base-16.0.0.pom' first, what annoys me is that downloading is very slow and AS download it once and once again,that means I need at least 3 minutes to finish building my project every time,however, most of time is spent on downloading...

[image]

Does anyone have solutions or advice? why AS download it once and once again? how can I solve this Problem to speed up my building?

Answer (score 0):

I just do nothing, and I do not care about this problem for about two days, it disappered automaticly, what a strange!